# remove a specific word using sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a simple question

I have this file :

```
[NOC_S_Z_1]
    callerid=NULL
    secret=NOC_S_Z_1
    context=CallCenterGWs
    type=peer
    host=dynamic

[NOC_S_A_2]
    callerid=NULL
    secret=NOC_S_A_2
    context=CallCenterGWs
    type=peer
    host=dynamic
[5154]
    callerid=<5154>
    secret=5154
    context=SupportGroup
    type=friend
    host=dynamic

[5155]
    callerid=<5155>
    secret=5155
    context=SupportGroup
    type=friend
    host=dynamic
[PRIGW]
    callerid=NULL
    secret=PRI18865
    context=CallCenterGWs
    type=peer
    host=192.168.2.95
```

I want to use sed or awk command to look for this word `callerid=NULL` and remove it , but here is the trick , i want it to remove the line above it and the 4 lines below it !
it's a very large file but it's all the same type and the `callerid=NULL` is randomly sorted in the file

I managed to remove only the `callerid=NULL` but this is not helping

Any idea would be helpfull.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 It's already in code form , can you please tell me if i'm missing anything ? thank you

Comment: `I want to use sed or awk command to look for this word` whichever command/code you have tried you could add in your question, as its highly encouraged on StackOverflow. Else you may get close votes for your question, thank you.

Comment: I have put every code in code form , the rest is just a text of me explaining the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `[` always denotes start of new block I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
[NOC_S_Z_1]
    callerid=NULL
    secret=NOC_S_Z_1
    context=CallCenterGWs
    type=peer
    host=dynamic

[NOC_S_A_2]
    callerid=NULL
    secret=NOC_S_A_2
    context=CallCenterGWs
    type=peer
    host=dynamic
[5154]
    callerid=<5154>
    secret=5154
    context=SupportGroup
    type=friend
    host=dynamic

[5155]
    callerid=<5155>
    secret=5155
    context=SupportGroup
    type=friend
    host=dynamic
[PRIGW]
    callerid=NULL
    secret=PRI18865
    context=CallCenterGWs
    type=peer
    host=192.168.2.95
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="["}NR>1&&!/callerid=NULL/{printf "[%s",$0}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
[5154]
    callerid=<5154>
    secret=5154
    context=SupportGroup
    type=friend
    host=dynamic

[5155]
    callerid=<5155>
    secret=5155
    context=SupportGroup
    type=friend
    host=dynamic
```

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that row separator is `[` then I use `printf` to output records excluding first one (`NR>1`, empty string before first `[`) and those with `callerid=NULL` inside (negated regular expression). I do prepend `[` to record as it is treated as row separator, i.e. not included in record.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: This works ! can you please explain each meaning in your awk ?

Comment: i understand how you deleted the above line and the callerid=NULL , but how you delete the 4 below lines ?

Comment: @resha gimmick is to use `[` as row separator (`RS`), then everything between `[` and next `[` is seen as single row by GNU `AWK`

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution could be something like this:

```
sed '/^\[/!b
     N
     /callerid=NULL/!b
     N;N;N;N;d
' file
```